# DATAGRIDVIEW Operator '=' is not defined for type 'DBNull' and type 'Integer'

Tags: vb.net

below is my code,  when i want to select the user it complains that  Operator '=' is not defined for type 'DBNull' and type 'Integer'.

```
If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
    Dim i As Integer

    i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
    'UserID is a variable holding a value in database field of User_ID
    publicRegistrationId = DataGridView1.Item(1, i).Value
    userName_txt.Text = DataGridView1.Item(3, i).Value
    adminRight_chk.Checked = IIf(DataGridView1.Item(4, i).Value = 0, False, True)
    financeRight_chk.Checked = IIf(DataGridView1.Item(5, i).Value = 0, False, True)
    operationRight_chk.Checked = IIf(DataGridView1.Item(6, i).Value = 0, False, True)
    salesRight_chk.Checked = IIf(DataGridView1.Item(7, i).Value = 0, False, True)
    'ministry_txt.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(Trim(Dr("ministry"))), "", Trim(Dr("ministry")))
End If
```

Comment: I don't think you can call Trim on a Null. Try the If() instead of IIF(). It is short circuited so the the third parameter is not evaluated if True. This will prevent an error.

Answer (score 0):

Because one of the entries that is an `INT` (`Int32`) is nullable and contains `Null` (`DBNull`). Null values are not returned as `Nothing` as you might expect for the simple reason that in .NET 1.0 when this was created there didn't exist any nullable value types.

I think there are no ready made extension methods for the `DataGridViewRows` like there are for `DataRows` (i.e. `DataRow.Field<T>()`) but you can create you own functions like this:

```
Public Sub Foo()
    Dim DataGridView1 As DataGridView = Nothing
    If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
        Dim currentRow As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.CurrentRow
        'UserID is a variable holding a value in database field of User_ID
        publicRegistrationId = ToInt32Nullable(GetValue(currentRow, 1))
        userName_txt.Text = ToString(GetValue(currentRow, 3))
        adminRight_chk.Checked = ToBoolean(GetValue(currentRow, 4))
        financeRight_chk.Checked = ToBoolean(GetValue(currentRow, 5))
        operationRight_chk.Checked = ToBoolean(GetValue(currentRow, 6))
        salesRight_chk.Checked = ToBoolean(GetValue(currentRow, 7))
        ministry_txt.Text = ToString(GetValue(currentRow, "ministry"))
    End If
End Sub

Private Shared Function GetValue(row As DataGridViewRow, columnIndex As Int32) As Object
    Dim result As Object = row.Cells(columnIndex).Value
    If (TypeOf result Is DBNull) Then Return Nothing
    Return result
End Function

Private Shared Function GetValue(row As DataGridViewRow, columnIndex As String) As Object
    Dim result As Object = row.Cells(columnIndex).Value
    If (TypeOf result Is DBNull) Then Return Nothing
    Return result
End Function

Private Shared Function ToInt32Nullable(value As Object) As Int32?
    If (value Is Nothing) Then Return Nothing
    If (TypeOf value Is Int32) Then Return CInt(value)
    Dim stringValue As String = value.ToString()
    Dim result As Int32
    If (Int32.TryParse(stringValue, NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, result)) Then
        Return result
    End If
    Throw New InvalidCastException($"Value '{stringValue}' cannot be cast into an {NameOf(Int32)}!")
End Function

Private Shared Shadows Function ToString(value As Object) As String
    If (value Is Nothing) Then Return Nothing
    If (TypeOf value Is String) Then Return CStr(value).Trim()
    Return value.ToString()
End Function

Private Shared Function ToBoolean(value As Object) As Boolean
    If (value Is Nothing) Then Return False
    If (TypeOf value Is Boolean) Then
        Return CType(value, Boolean)
    End If
    Dim stringValue As String = value.ToString().Trim()
    Dim stringValueLC As String = stringValue.ToLowerInvariant()
    Select Case stringValueLC
        Case "", "0", "false", "off", "no", "disabled", "denied"
            Return False
        Case "1", "true", "on", "yes", "enabled", "granted"
            Return True
    End Select
    Throw New InvalidCastException($"Value '{stringValue}' cannot be cast into a {NameOf(System.Boolean)}!")
End Function
```

Comment: thank you for our efforts but its not working out

Comment: If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then                                                                                           If (Int32.TryParse(stringValue, NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, result)) Then
            Return result
        End If.    numberstyle and cultureinfo is the problem.